# Port bridging for torrents?

Tags: networking, routing, bittorrent

In organization they block the torrent ports, is there any concept of port mapping or bridging for example a server allow only `8080` and `443` and few basic ports and block all other ports so can we bridge any other ports on `8080` to make it fool ?

Comment: If your company is blocking torrent then the probably do it for a reason. Security and not having users waste precious resources that others could be using for legitimate work purposes are two reasons. If work are kind enough to pay you to do a job the least you could do is not waste their resources downloading the latest honey boo boo episodes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about circumventing corporate IT policy

Answer (score 1):

"Bridging" is not a term you want to use in this situation.

Tell your torrent program to listen on a port other than the default, such as 8080 or 443.  Look in any configuration options or menus.

To further avoid blocking based on packet inspection, enable encryption.  If your torrent program doesn't support it, switch to one that does.

Do the same for the DHT port in your torrent program, change it from any default.

Also disable uPnP.

If you cannot forward an incoming port from your Internet-facing router to your torrent program, your torrents will operate more slowly, but they will operate.  You will have to live with this if you cannot control the Internet facing router.